# Region created from point array fills window

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, graphics

I have a weird problem concerning the `Region` object.

I created a method which returns the `Region` defined by an array of `Point3D` (which is just a 3-float struct) which are converted to `PointF`.(`Face` is the face of a 3d cube)

```
public Region GetRegion(params Point3D[] facePoints)
{
    float distance = Camera3DLib.Camera3D.GetDistance();
    PointF[] planePoints = new PointF[links.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < planePoints.Length; i++)
    {
        planePoints[i] = facePoints[i].ToPointF(distance);
    }
    GraphicsPath pth = new GraphicsPath();
    pth.AddPolygon(planePoints);
    return new Region(pth);

}
```

The problem is displaying this region.

When I use `FillRegion`, the `graphics` fills everything *except* the `region`.
To get the region needed to fill, I use the above method a number of times (`Solid3D` contains an array of `Face3D` and an array of vertices, I hope the purpose of the methods that I use are self explanatory by their names)

```
private static Region GetVisibleRegion(Solid3D s)
{
    Region visible = new Region();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.GetFaces().Length; i++)
    {
        Face3D face = s.GetFaces()[i];
        Point3D[] facePoints = s.GetFaceVertices(i);

        Region region = face.GetRegion(facePoints);
        visible.Union(region);
    }
    return visible;
}
```

The drawing itself is done in a method called from the `Form_paint` event:

```
gr.FillRegion(Brushes.Blue, GetVisibleRegion(arr[0].Key));
```

`gr` is the graphics and `arr` is a dictionary who's key is a `Solid3D`.

This causes everything *except* the faces to be added to the `Region`.

What would be the cause of this?

I thought maybe the object, being passed by pointers between methods, is somehow getting reset (to default values of members) but I'm not so sure that's it.

PS: The code I wrote doesn't throw exceptions, so (I think) it's a logic or usage problem. If there are any questions about parts of the implementation that which aren't posted here (it's a lot of code :P) please ask.

Thanks!

Comment: @TaW the endpoint is being able to know if two faces intersect.

Comment: You may want to draw the intermediate GraphicsPaths to see if they are still ok. Can you show an image of the result? I wopuld assume the default windingMode of the GP works for you..